# Wrong conversion from String to List<CustomObject> and List<String> with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, converters

I have a Spring form with textarea inputs `inputTextA` and `inputTexB`
I need to bind those inputs to the following `Model` object:

```
public class Model{
    private List<String> listA;
    private List<CustomObject> listB;
    // getters and setters
}
```

I read that Spring is able to do the conversion automatically if I implement the Converter interface and register the implementation on the Spring configuration class. So I expect  Spring to do the following:

- `inputA = "12345|67890"` is converted to`model.listA = {"12345","12345"}`
- `inputB = "abcd|efgh"` is converted to `model.listB = {new CustomObject("abcd"),new CustomObject("efgh")}`

but I get the following:

- `inputA = "12345|67890"` is converted to`model.listA = {(new CustomObject("12345")).toString(),(new CustomObject("67890")).toString()}`
- `inputB = "abcd|efgh"` is converted to `model.listB = {new CustomObject("abcd"),new CustomObject("efgh")}`

I implemented the Converter Interface for each list as follows:

```
public class StringToStringListConverter implements Converter<String, List<String>>{
    @Override
    public List<String> convert(String source){
        List<String> result = null;
        // Conversion logic.
        return result;
    }
}
```

,

```
public class StringToCustomObjectListConverter implements Converter<String, List<CustomObject>>{
    @Override
    public List<CustomObject> convert(String source){
        List<CustomObject> result = null;
        // Conversion logic.
        return result;
    }
}
```

and register each converter on the Spring Configuration class overriding the addFormatter method.

```
@Override
public void addFormatter(FormatterRegistry registry){
    registry.addConverter(new StringToStringListConverter());
    registry.addConverter(new StringToCustomObjectListConverter());
}
```

I have the following view.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputTextAId" class="col-form-label col-sm-2">
        <spring:message code="labelAText"/>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <form:textarea id="inputTextAId"
                    class="form-control"
                    rows="3"
                    path="model.stringListA">
        </form:textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputTextBId" class="col-form-label col-sm-2">
        <spring:message code="labelBText"/>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <form:textarea id="structuresId" 
                       class="form-control"
                       rows="3"
                       path="model.stringListB">
        </form:textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```